# Error in preprocessing with tm package in R

Tags: r, package, tm

I am trying to do some preprocessing with tm package in R. I wrote the lines below:

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(Data))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus , asPlain)
corpus <- tmMap(corpus , removeSignature)
```

As you can see, I tried both 'tm_map' and 'tmMap'. But I faced these errors each time:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'asPlain' not found
Error: could not find function "tmMap"
```

Could you please help me to solve this error?

Comment: The error message is clear: package `tm` don't contain `asPlain` neither `tmMap` functions.

Comment: I assume you didn't forget to import tm package?

Comment: @agstudy Really? I didn't know that. I am beginner in R and I got familiar with tmMap in tm's mannual. Which package contains that?

Comment: @Woodface Yes, I imported tm package.

Comment: You should just use `tm_map`.  i.e: `tm_map(corpus , removeSignature)`

Comment: @agstudy I did exactly as you said and this error came up: Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'removeSignature' not found

Answer (score 0):

The tm package changed the function calls and some of those methods are no longer available.

Here is some sample code with the new functions.

```
require(tm)
text_corpus <- VCorpus( DirSource("20ng_train/sci.electronics"))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(text_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeNumbers) 
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removeWords, stopwords()) 
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, removePunctuation)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, stemDocument)
corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus_clean, stripWhitespace)
```